# What should i use as a window sill for this space?

Tags: windows, window-frame

I worry that water will run down the side of the house and could be contributing to the damp below the bay window. I would like to install some kind of window sill but wondering if anyone has advice on what to do. There is only a gap of 20mm between the window opening and the recessed wall. It is quite deep as well (200mm) and 800mm length

[image: 1]

Comment: Another photo from a distance would help

Comment: What is on the other windows? As long as what you fit is water proof and fitted correctly (running water away from the house with a lip so it drips rather than run down the wall) this is more of an aesthetic choice - good idea to try to match it to the other windows.

Comment: What's the blob, lower left?  Also, got a pic from the inside, preferably with the window open?